# How can I make changes to the Windows Registry persistent?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I want to make changes to the Windows Registry through a Powershell script. I use the old fashioned reg add approach and it works quite well. If I run regedit.exe after my script all changes are made but they are lost after a reboot ...

My code:

```
# Enable Auto Logon
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v "AutoAdminLogon" /t REG_SZ /d "1" > null

$name = Read-Host 'Username'
# Set username for logon
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v "DefaultUserName" /t REG_SZ /d $name > null

# Set users password
$clearPassword = Read-Host 'Password' 
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v "DefaultPassword" /t REG_SZ /d $clearPassword > null

# How many times to auto logon? (0 means infinitive)
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v "AutoLogonCount" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" > null

echo "Autologon enabled"
```

So, what can I do to make these changes persistent in the Windows Registry?

Best regards

peekaboo777

Comment: Changes made to the registry are always "persistent", unless you've got some application installed that is ensuring otherwise. Computers in public areas (e.g., school labs, libraries, etc.) often have this type of software installed. I remember something called DeepFreeze from my younger years.

Comment: I'm running this script on my home computer. So I don't think that this type of software is installed on my computer ;-)

I've read that the changes made to Registry are flushed to disk at shutdown but in my special case they're not accepted or changed by a "higher instance" in Windows. Any clue where I can start searching for this "instance"?

Comment: Well, the problem may be that you need to elevate when running the script. If you don't have the requisite privileges, you can't edit the registry. But then if that's the case, you should get an error and/or your changes shouldn't show up.

Comment: I've found the problem with this script. 

The command 

    _# How many times to auto logon? (0 means infinitive)
    reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v "AutoLogonCount" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" > null_

is used wrong. If I remove this line the script behaves as expected. I think I've put a wrong value into this entry and so Windows reverts all my changes I've made to Winlogon.

Comment: It probably doesn't *revert* them, it probably just *ignores* them. You're allowed to make invalid changes to the registry. The system doesn't fix them automatically. You just get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Anyway, you should have posted that as an *answer* to your question, rather than a comment. That way, you can mark your question as answered (though you have to wait a while for self-answered questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is by design.

On each reboot, Windows will de-crement the AutoLogonCount. When it is at zero, the registry value is removed to disable auto-logon. The values for  DefaultUserName and DefaultPassword may also be cleared.

This feature is generally used during automated Windows client builds/deployments.

This is well documented. E.g. http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_auto_logon.htm